# json/xml dump to MSSQL Server or MySQL automation

Tags: mysql, sql-server, json, xml, scheduled-tasks

I have access to an API which give me access to a specific database table(s) and their records. while it is convenient in some cases, i have a scenario where I am hosting the same database in my server but then i need to daily go and fetch the data as json/xml file and then convert it with some hardcoded scripts into my local db.

My question is, is there any efficient tool or way to simply and directly import these json/xml dumps into the database. I am open to MySql or MSSQLSERVER while Currently I am using MSSQL. I am interested in an approach where we can set up daily incremental updates in my local db server.

Converting json to sql is really a pain sometime because most of the records are addresses and messages, and database is quite big. a normal day json dump is almost 20 mb.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 has [JSON](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2016/query-output-data-in-json-format-support-for-sqlserver-developers.aspx) support for converting data to JSON format and parsing JSON data to tabular format

Comment: I have SQL SERVER 2014, if no other way is possible i can switch to 16. No alternative method?

Comment: Hi Shahzad, please check article https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/